# $.Deferred reject ignored and does not fire any callbacks in a specific situation

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I'm trying to make a fade in that stops the fade out where it is and fades in starting at the opacity the fade out left off at. Currently, the first time I type a key, if I interrupt the fadeOut with another keystroke, it'll cause `animOpacityPromise` to never resolve no matter what until a page refresh. If I let the fadeOut complete, any subsequent `animOpacityPromiseCtrl.reject();` will be ignored until a page refresh, allowing the fadeOut to complete. For example, in the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tsv53gd4/2/), if I type a key, wait until I see `clearOverlay animate promise completed` in the log, then type in "ABC", wait for it to start fading out and interrupt it's fade out with "SS", the overlay will instantly disappear on the first S and reappear with the content "SS" on the second S. The expected behavior is for it to not clear the searchString and overlay until the overlay is finished fading out and instead interrupt the fadeout with a fade in and append the keys to the search string and overlay. If I interrupt the first fadeout with a keystroke, the animation behavior is how I want with the fade in that stops the fade out where it is and fades in starting at the opacity the fade out left off at but `animOpacityPromise.done` and `animOpacityPromise.always` will never be called in any keystroke until a page refresh.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tsv53gd4/2/)

```
function initQuickSearch() {
  var overlay = $('#searchOverlay');
  var overlayIsFadingOut = false;
  var fadeOutTimeOut;
  var searchString = '';
  var animOpacityPromiseCtrl = $.Deferred();

  function showOverlay() {
    var fadeDelay = 200;

    if (overlayIsFadingOut) {
      console.log('clearOverlay animate promise rejected');
      animOpacityPromiseCtrl.reject();
      overlayIsFadingOut = false;
      clearTimeout(fadeOutTimeOut);
      fadeDelay = 100;
    }
    overlay.css({'visibility': 'visible'});
    overlay.stop(true, false).animate({opacity: 1}, {duration: fadeDelay, queue: true}, 'easeOutQuint');
  }

  function clearOverlay(bool) {
    var fadeDelay = 1000;
    var fadeDuration = 400;
    var animOpacityPromise;

    if (bool === true) {
      fadeDelay = 0;
      fadeDuration = 200;
    }

    overlayIsFadingOut = true;

    fadeOutTimeOut = setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('clearOverlay setTimeout called');
      animOpacityPromise = $.when(overlay.animate(
        {opacity: 0},
        {
          duration: fadeDuration,
          queue: true,
          start: function() {
            console.log('Fade out started.');
          },
          done: function() {
            console.log('Fade out done. Resolving promise.');
            animOpacityPromiseCtrl.resolve();
          }
        },
      'easeOutQuint').promise(), animOpacityPromiseCtrl);

      animOpacityPromise.done(function() {
        console.log('clearOverlay animate promise completed');
        overlay.css({'visibility': 'hidden'});
        searchString = '';
        $('#searchOverlay span').html('');
      });

      animOpacityPromise.always(function() {
        console.log('clearOverlay animate promise always');
        overlayIsFadingOut = false;
      });
    }, fadeDelay);
  }

  function addChar(char) {
    searchString = searchString + String.fromCharCode(char.which);
    console.log('Character "' + String.fromCharCode(char.which) + '" added to searchString. searchString is now "' + searchString + '"');

    $('#searchOverlay span').append(String.fromCharCode(char.which));
  }

  function removeChar() {
    searchString = searchString.substring(0, searchString.length - 1);
    $('#searchOverlay span').text(function(iter, txt) {
      return txt.slice(0, -1);
    });
  }

  $(window).keydown(function(key) {
    //If it's not an alphabetical character or the backspace key.
    if (!(key.which > 64 && key.which < 91) && key.which != 8) {
    } else {
      showOverlay();
      clearOverlay();
      if (key.which == 8) {
        removeChar();
      } else if (searchString.length <= 20) {
        addChar(key);
        key.preventDefault();
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

  overlay.click(function() {
    clearOverlay(true);
  });
}
```

Comment: After a few more debug messages added, I've discovered that the promise always was being called before before it could be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was it kept reusing the same promise object. So I've assigned `animOpacityPromiseCtrl` to a new deferred object every time `clearOverlay` was called and it fixed the problem.

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tsv53gd4/3/).